# InputSource to String Conversion in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, string, xml-parsing, saxparser

I have created InputSource object using my entire string xml request in my application and I am trying to fetch entire xml request from the created InputSource reference. Please find below code snippet and advise some code/ways to get the xmlRequest from the InputSource reference.

org.xml.sax.InputSource is = new org.xml.sax.InputSource(new StringReader(xmlRequest));

Now I wish to get xmlRequest from InputSource reference 'is'.

Can anybody please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can live with recreating the request from the `Reader`, it's simple too:

```
    InputSource is=new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlRequest));
    Reader r=is.getCharacterStream();
    r.reset(); // Ensure to read the complete String
    StringBuilder b=new StringBuilder();
    int c;
    while((c=r.read())>-1)
        b.appendCodePoint(c);
    r.reset(); // Reset for possible further actions
    String xml=b.toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't get the `String` back out of the `StringReader`.
Either you assign the `xmlRequest` to a variable of its own or you have to create your own `StringReader`, which does that:

```
private static class OwnStringReader extends StringReader
{
    private final String content;

    public OwnStringReader(String content)
    {
        super(content);
        this.content=content;
    }

    public String getContent()
    {
        return content;
    }
}
```

Then you can retrieve your `String` by

```
    InputSource is=new InputSource(new OwnStringReader(xmlRequest));
    String xml=((OwnStringReader)is.getCharacterStream()).getContent();
```

Comment: 'You can't get the `String` back out of the `StringReader`": of course you can. Just read all the characters, append then to a `StringBuilder`, and then get the string back from the builder.

Comment: @user207421 But it's a) not the same String and b) the Reader has to be reset afterwards (and probably before too).